# Previous answer being remembered if new options contain it RadioGroup Shadcn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a quiz app which features multiple questions with pagination. Each question has 4 possible answers, but user can only choose one.

Consider the scenario:

- On question 1, user selects the answer "Hippo".
- Question 2 happens to have "Hippo" as one of the options. When the user navigates to this question, the "Hippo" option is already selected. I want to know why and how to fix it. This only happens when *adjacent* questions have "Hippo" as one of the options.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-surf-54lxt4

Here is my `RadioGroup` from shadcn. Even if I remove value prop completely, still the same issue.

```js
<RadioGroup
  value={props.savedAnswers[questionIndex]?.answer}
  onValueChange={(chosenAnswer) => {
    props.saveAnswer(chosenAnswer)
  }}
>
  {choiceElements}
</RadioGroup>
```

`props.saveAnswer` looks like this

```js
const saveAnswer = (answer: string) => {
  setSavedAnswers((savedAnswers) => {
    const newAnswersState = { ...savedAnswers }
    newAnswersState[questionIndex] = {
      answer
    }
    
    return newAnswersState
  })
}
```

```
export type SavedAnswers = {
  [key: number]: {
    answer: string
    isCorrect?: boolean
    checked?: boolean
  }
}
```

Next and previous buttons merely change `questionIndex`. Here is how my `RadioGroupItem` looks like, rendered with map `props.questionOptions((answerText, i) => ...)`.

```js
<div key={answerText}>
  <RadioGroupItem
    value={answerText}
    disabled={props.savedAnswers[questionIndex]?.checked}
    id={answerText}
  />
  <Label htmlFor={answerText}>{answerText}</Label>
</div>
```

Comment: An answer should not only be defined by its text value, it should have its own unique identifier, or at least a relative identifier with access to the ID of the question itself. That way, if two answers have the same content, they won't be considered the same because they belong to different questions.

Comment: `SavedAnswers` should be `{ answer, id, isCorrect, ... }`.

Comment: I'll try that, but the question is, why does it not distinguish between different answers when `savedAnswers` is key (index) based object? How does it select "Hippo" for question 2, even if it is stored for the first question index in `savedAnswers`?

Comment: `RadioGroupItem` is identified by `answerText`, which is the same for both answers, React won't be able to distinguish them in consequence.

Comment: React will be able to distinguish `<div key={answerText}>`, but not the `RadioGroupItem` inside it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "`RadioGroupItem` is identified by `answerText`"? In which place does React "use" `answerText` for both of the questions? In `RadioGroup`'s `value` prop, there is distinct `questionIndex` selection before grabbing stored `answerText`, even if same for two different questions.

Comment: It doesn't matter the different index, React does not look at how you got the value, it just looks if there is a different value or not. If `savedAnswers[0].answer` and `savedAnswers[1].answer` are the same, then React won't distinguish between them, it only looks at the value.

Comment: Got it, one more question, how is this same answer persisted when changing `questionIndex` results in re-render? When I click the next button, `props.savedAnswers[questionIndex]?.answer` returns `undefined`. Isn't the `value` of `RadioGroup` the source of truth for the radio inputs? If it's `undefined`, how does an answer get selected?

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing the code as a whole, but it looks like the value is not undefined when you move to the next question. It would help if you could provide a runnable [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-surf-54lxt4

Comment: If you change your `questionPool.choices` to objects like `{id: "q1a1", text: "Option 1"}`, where "q1a1" means question 1 answer 1 and similarly to the other answers, also change to `<RadioGroupItem value={answer.id}`. It will fix your problem.

Comment: That fixes it, thanks, but I would have liked to understand why was "Hippo" being selected when `props.savedAnswers[questionIndex]?.answer` returned `undefined` on second question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks to be where you've not set the checked property on the RadioGroupItem.

```
        <RadioGroupItem
          value={answerText}
          checked={
            props.savedAnswers[props.questionIndex]?.answer === answerText
          }
          disabled={props.savedAnswers[props.questionIndex]?.checked}
          id={answerText}
        />
```

this this what you were hoping for?

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-chebyshev-nfwtxf

Comment: That way, I'm not able to select "Hippo" if it was selected in the first question. For some reason, it looks like `saveAnswer` function does not run on the second question.

Comment: thats because of the disabled prop 
disabled={props.savedAnswers[props.questionIndex]?.checked}
if you dont want it do be disabled then remove that prop, I just left it in from your example.